# AWS Lambda function upload

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, twilio, alexa-skills-kit

In creating a new function, I have zipped up the `index.js` and `node_modules` that I need for the project. The modules include the `alexa-sdk` and `twilio`. My `index.js` has an `export.handler` function.

Two questions

1) Do I have to have a `package.json` file in the upload?
 2) Does the upload file name have to match the configuration handler?

After the upload I cannot use the inline code editor to work on the `index.js` file, it says it is too large.

Comment: What problem are you experiencing exactly... that your file is too large to edit?

Comment: That is correct but the index.js file is rather small , in fact I used it in other skills that I have live and running. My biggest issue is that I am doing an upgrade of a skill I have running but need the twilio sdk for the new features I want to add.

Comment: The deployment package of your Lambda function "MedTimeII" is too large to enable inline code editing. However, you can still invoke your function right now

Comment: Additionally, you don't even have to include `node_modules/aws-sdk`, as lambda will use it's own version anyway. This saves about 5MB zipped. This is my go to zip command: `zip -r ../skill.zip * --exclude '*.DS_Store*' '*.git*' '*.vscode*' 'node_modules/aws-sdk/*'`

Answer (score 1):

1. The zip filename does not change the lambda behavior.
2. Lambda console will use the code in (filename.handler_function) to call your lambda. In this case your handler should be index.handler.

If you want to speed up your import/edit/upload lambda functions you can use a cli tool like [lambda-toolkit](https://github.com/lucioveloso/lambda-toolkit).

Comment: Correct I am using the index.handler , what I expected to see was my index.js file in the inline code editor and then be able to call functions from the twilio library. my index.js file is only 20kb

Answer (score 0):

1. No, As long as you've installed the node_modules like the alexa-sdk
   you don't need package.json.
2. Lambda will use index.js.
3. It would be nice to edit index.js in the inline code editor. 
   Unfortunately that's not an available option.  Instead each time you
   edit your code you'll need to re-zip and re-upload.  Also the name
   doesn't matter.  I name mine foo.zip.

Comment: thanks for the follow up and you are right , just unfortunate that they have not re-worked the create function to show the index.js file after the upload

Comment: apparently it has been said that once doing an upload you cannot use the inline code editor. I decided to just check and test a download of the files I uploaded and made all the changes necessary using vscode, uploaded and all the modules are loaded and the application works. You just cant use the inline editor for quick changes and test . you will need to upload each time you make a change to you js file

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to include `package.json` in the zip file for upload.

If your uploaded zip file **exceeds 3MB**, you wont be able to use the inline code editor.

> If the size of your Lambda function's zipped deployment packages
>   exceeds 3MB, you will not be able to use the inline code editing
>   feature in the Lambda console. You can still use the console to invoke
>   your Lambda function.

More on AWS Lambda limits [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)